# How to use Hazelcast with TomEE 7?

Tags: hazelcast, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have to load data in memory while doing the server startup. I am planning to use Hazelcast and application server is TomEE 7. Can anyone help with this requirement?

Comment: Do you want to start Hazelcast nodes on our own using a Provider or CDI? Please clarify the question.

Comment: I am not planning to use separate Hazelcast nodes. Need to load data from DB to instance memory while starting TomEE server. Later I can reuse those data for computation without going for a DB lookup.

Comment: That is not really a use case for Hazelcast. Hazelcast is not designed as a single-instance in-process cache. You can find faster / better alternatives by using Ehcache or Guava.

Comment: Thanks noctarius I am thinking about using ehCache instead. Thank you for  your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TomEE 7 has JCS built in (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/) in the plus version, can be a good start too

Comment: Thanks Romain. Do you prefer JCS over EhCache?

Comment: Both are good and not 100% exactly the same but for local caching my proposal was to use what was built in and look for another impl if needed more than the opposite. Doesnt mean ehcache is bad at all.